# Navigate to HTML page using ng-click

Tags: html, angularjs

I have button that I want it to :

1. Call multiple functions from the controller using `ng-click`(and I have to call them in HTML)
2. Navigate to another html page placed in "`static/page.html`"

`onclick`, when used to navigate (location.href), is override `ng-click`! Even when binding all the functions.

Here is the button tag :

```
<div ng-repeat="object in nc.objects">
 <button ng-click="fun1(object.id); fun2(object.name);">
 button
 </button>
```

button

```
$scope.fun1 = function (id) {

        var url = "/req/"+id;
        var Request = $http.get(url);
        Request.then(function (response) {
            $localStorage.var1  = response.data;

        });

    }

    $scope.fun2 = function (name) {

        var url = "/otherReq/"+name;
        var Request = $http.get(url);
        Request.then(function (response) {
            $localStorage.var2  = response.data;

        });

    }
```

ngRoute

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.

        when('/page2', {
            templateUrl: 'page2.html' <!-- also tried static/page2.html  but not working -->
        });

    }]);
```

in HTML

```
<button ng-click = "navigate(object.id, object.name, '/page2' )" > </button>
```

[image: Folder Structure]

Comment: Why not defining a function that does it all and calling it with ng-click?

Comment: @Ryan.Hunt How can I navigate to HTML page with angularJS function?

Comment: Are you using ng-route or ui-router? Those are standard libraries to navigate your application the way you intend.

Answer (score 1):

Build some functions in your controller, and bind them to your ng-click. Like this way:

```
<button ng-click="clicked(object.id, 'page.html')>
```

and in your controller:

```
$scope.clicked = function(id, name, url){
    $scope.fun1(id);
    $scope.fun2(name); //or whatever you need to do..
    window.location = url; //this will change your browser location to the one specified.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. The problem is the functions are retrieving some rows from the DB and your solution navigates without retrieving the rows, where the rows are needed in the next page.

Comment: If you need to fetch data and make it available on next page, you need to make use of ng-route or ui-router to make it easier. If you do not want to use those, you'll still have to create a service/factory to make your calls, store your data, and inject it in your next page's controller.

Comment: @vgrafe I'm using $localstorage service and it works well, I just need to navigate at the same time of retrieving, is it possible with  $localstorage ?

Comment: you can, but if you are getting the data remotely from an api, you have to wait for that api call to be resolved before navigating. can you share your `fun1` and `fun2` functions ?

Comment: @vgrafe The question is updated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Oh boy, you are doing this all wrong. You don't need to navigate to another page from HTML. And you definitely shouldn't use `onclick` when working with Angular. That is just not the right way.

The way you'd want to do this is :

```
<button ng-click="objectClicked(object.id, object.name, someAngularRoute)>
```

Now before we move on, you need to understand what angularRoute is here.
By route, I mean a view associated with `someAngularRoute`.
Here `someAngularRoute` is basically your base url + `someAngularRoute`

So, when you say you want to open `page1.html` on button click, then you probably mean you want to open the route `page1` whose `templateUrl`(or VIEW) is `page1.html`.

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      // will open the the window url is www.example.com/page1
      when('/page1', {
        templateUrl: 'static/page1.html' 
      }).
      // will open the the window url is www.example.com/page2
      when('/page2', {
        templateUrl: 'static/page2.html'  
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/404'
      });
  }]);
```

And then in the controller:

```
$scope.objectClicked = function (id, name, someAngularRoute) {
      func1(id);
      func2(name);
      $location.path(someAngularRoute);
    }
```

**Ensure the $location is injected into your controller.**

**UPDATE**

@vgrafe is right. I didn't see your updated question with `fun1()` making requests. But with so many things wrong, I kinda just lost track. ;)

Comment: Thank you, The $location.path(page); is not working well!  The url became: http://localhost:8080/html/page1.html#/page2.html .

Comment: The URL is not working:( the URL becomes the previous page URL + /page1 :$ ,I think the problem is that I added my HTML pages in a static folder, not template. Thank you, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Show your directory structure and add your routing. That'll make things clear

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, upon click on that link, you want to :

- make an api call
- store the data in localstorage
- navigate to the next page

What is missing from your approach is asynchronous management. The page is navigated directly an before letting the api calls return any data, which always take a short moment.

Luxor001's solution is a good first step, but probably need to wait for `fun1` and/or `fun2` to be done before navigating. Look up how promises work.

I think SLearner is the closest to the solution, but is not resolving the asynchonous api calls in his routing.

To leverage the async nature of your http calls, you need to return them from your functions.

Something like this would work :

```
$scope.fun1 = function (id) {
    var url = "/req/"+id;
    var Request = $http.get(url);
    return Request.then(function (response) {
        $localStorage.var1  = response.data;
    });
}

$scope.fun2 = function (name) {
    var url = "/otherReq/"+name;
    var Request = $http.get(url);
    return Request.then(function (response) {
        $localStorage.var2  = response.data;
    });
}

$scope.objectClicked = function (id, name, someAngularRoute) {
  $scope.func1(id)
  .then(function(func1result) {
      return $scope.func2(name);
  })
  .then(function(func2result) {
       $location.path(someAngularRoute);
  });
}
```

That being said, SLearner is right: you are doing everything wrong here :)

You should articulate your app's routing around ng-route of ui-router, and resolve the api calls in those routes. There are many tutorials in each of those libs documentations that will lead you into understanding how to write app routing properly.